# Up-to-date Fiddler equivalent for OS X?

Tags: gratis, osx

I'm looking for a locally running web debugging proxy for OS X like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for Windows.
Fiddler claims to offer an OS X version as well, but it was last updated in 2013 and doesn't work all that well on the latest releases of OS X.

What would be a fitting alternative? I need to monitor all in- and outgoing HTTP & HTTPS traffic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two alternatives come to mind:

- [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com), which is actually multi-platform as it uses Java. So it's not native OSX. It's frequently updated, has a wide range of features and good support.
- [Cellist](http://cellist.patr0n.us/index.html), a native OSX app, simpler to use and does not have all the bells and whistles like Charles. It does what it's supposed to do though.

If you're looking for something completely free, have a look at [mitmproxy](http://mitmproxy.org/doc/mitmproxy.html). It's a multi-platform console app, so it might be a bit harder to use.